# In what situation you must work on a debug build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Given the fact that you can debug in release build as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fsk896zz.aspx, in what situation do you really need to build a debug build in the development process?

Comment: Would you want to go through every project in a solution to do this or just build a debug solution and use that?

Comment: For instance my solution has 285 projects, I don't think modifying the project settings on everything is feasible when I can just build and execute a debug build that is designed for this

Comment: Saying that I tend to only modify the projects that need debugging, also I use print statements and WinDbg for my debugging

Comment: @EdChum Both VS projects and makefiles support include, in one way or another, and if you have more than one project, each should include a properties file with the settings you use.  There's really no other way of ensuring that all projects have compatible settings.

Comment: @JamesKanze that sounds like a bit of a pain but I do agree that, that would work. I work on quite a large code base and upgrading between versions of vc++ is painful so there are a lot of pointless flags and settings that are in there. Personally I rarely ever run debug because it is too slow for our product which is graphics intensive, I normally use windbg or just turn off optimisations and attach visual studio, or use print statements for gnarly multi-threaded bugs.

Comment: @EdChum It's a lot less of a pain than going through hundreds of projects, modifying each one at a time.  The project files are more or less standard XML, with in addition a very clean formatting, so are easy to edit directly; about the only modifications I do to them under VS is add and remove files.  (I use a Python script to generate a new empty project file, with all of my includes, etc. as I want them.)

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* debug the release configuration, the settings in the release configuration are for the release build (and probably should be seen/maintained as such, through the development lifecycle).

Changing them similar to that article is a step that you will probably have to revert at some point, unless sending debugging information to your clients is what you want to do.

In some projects there are three maintained build configurations:

- debug: supporting no optimizations and full diagnostics information (optimized for code maintenance, by the developers)
- release: build what the clients will see/buy
- release with debug symbols (similar to the link you ask about): this is for testing; the QA team will test something as similar as possible to what the clients will see, but in case it doesn't work, developers should have enough context information to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the type of application, but normally, you
won't want two different builds; you want to work and debug on
the same build you deliver.  What you call it is up to
you—you generally don't need a name for it, since it is
the only configuration you use.

This will typically be fairly close to what Microsoft calls the
Debug build; it will have `assert` active, for example, and not
do much optimizing

The exception is when performance is an issue.  If you find
yourself in a case where you cannot afford to leave asserts
active, bounds checking in arrays, etc., and you need
optimization in the code you deliver, you will probably want to
have two builds, one for testing and debugging, and one that you
deliver (which will also require testing).  The reason is, of
course, that it is very difficult to debug optimized code, since
the generated code doesn't always correspond too closely to what
you have written.  Also, a lot of debuggers (including both VS
and gdb, I think) are incapable of showing the values of
variables that the compiler has optimized into a register.

In many such cases, you may also want to create three builds;
iterator validation can be very, very expensive, and you may
want to have a build which turns that off, but still does no
optimizing.  (It's very painful to debug if you need to wait 20
minutes to reach the spot where the program fails.)

Comment: "normally" depends on your experience and industry niche. In most windows applications, having at least two build configurations is dead-useful (see my post above). In my (very subjective) experience *nix-like systems do not impose this as a practice, but most project builds end up supporting something similar throughout the duration of the project (e.g. you end up seeing in the documentation "run cmake with XYZ parameters to create a test/automated/release build" - or similar).

Comment: In most Windows applications, people have two build configurations because that's what VS gives you by default; they've never thought about it.  If you think about it, then you end up with what I said: you don't _want_ to deliver something different than what you've actually developed, tested and debugged.  You may have to, for performance reasons, but it's always a less than ideal solution.  (Of course, if you're doing fancy graphics, which is common in a lot of Windows applications, you may have performance issues.)

Answer (score 0):

The optimizations performed for the Release build make debugging harder.

For example,

```
a = c;
b = d;
```

In a Debug build, the compiled code will consist of four instructions:

1. read `c`
2. write `a`
3. read `d`
4. write `b`

That is fairly straightforward, and when stepping through the program line by line, executing the first line will run instructions 1 and 2, allowing me to examine the program state at this point afterwards.

In contrast, a Release build might notice that `a` and `b` are right next to each other in memory, as are `c` and `d`, so you could use a single access to read both `c` and `d` in one go, and write `a` and `b`.

Now we have only two instructions, and there is no clear mapping between source code lines and machine instructions. If you ask the debugger to step over the first line, it will execute both instructions (so you can see the result), but you never get the exact state between the two lines.

This is a simple example. Typically, the optimizer will try to comb instructions together so that the CPU is optimally loaded with instructions.

This especially means pulling memory reads to the front so they have a chance of being executed before the data is used in a calculation (otherwise, the CPU has to stop there and wait for the memory access to complete), mixing floating-point and integer operations (because these are run on different circuitry and can be parallelized), and calculating conditions for conditional jumps as early as possible (so the instruction prefetch mechanism knows whether to follow the jump or not).

In short, while debugging using a Release build is possible and sometimes necessary to reproduce customer bug reports, you really want the predictable behavior of a Debug build most of the time.